# Android Listview don't receive onItemClick with custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hey I made a custom viewgroup extends relative layout and override the onTouchEvent(), and always return true in onTouchEvent(). I make this custom viewgroup as my listview's item layout. I also add the onItemClick listener for the listview. But I can't receive onItemClick event for my listview! Could anybody help me?

Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

just difine onitemclick in the adapter class getView (... ) i think it will work for you

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
  vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return true in `onTouchEvent()`, the event is handled and thus does not bubble up to the ListView. Try returning false.

Comment: If I return false, then I can't get other MotionEvent later in my viewgroup. How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: How about if you return `super.onTouchEvent()`?

Comment: super.onTounchEvent()will return false at this case. And the viewgroup will not receive ACTION_UP event anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Using only onitemClick event is enough i guess as far as your question is concerned

Comment: No, I should do some work when MotionEvent down and MotionEvent up.

Comment: @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            doMyWork();

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            endMywork();

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you always return `true` from your ViewGroup's `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` method. That means that your relative layout is responsible for handling this touch events.
Read android documentation for more information http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html